# Using AWS Cloudfront, should I use apache gzip module to compress files or Cloudfront itself?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to get cloudfront straight on my site.

I want to know if I should you apache module to enable gzip on my site or set Cloudfront to compress the cached files?

Comment: I'd recommend cloudfront. Keep your server free to process something else.

Comment: Should i compress only JavaScript and css files ? I don't think compressing .JPG files is of any use. Kindly advise thanks!